# Netty long polling client aggregator never finds end of message

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, nio, long-polling

I have a long polling client implemented with Netty to accept a rest stream. It works if I take out the decompressor and the aggregator, but my chunk size is limited. I tried increasing the chunk size, which works, but I'm worried that at some point it's possible to receive an extra large message.

When I add the aggregator, as shown below, no data 'streams' through, it all gets collected and aggregated and dumped out at the end when the program terminates. How can I signal the aggregator that the message is finished? Or is there another approach I should be using. Thanks!

My handler is an implementation of SimpleChannelInboundHandler.

```
public class SecureNestChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

private final SslContext sslCtx;
private final NestStreamingClient client;

public SecureNestChannelInitializer(SslContext sslCtx, NestStreamingClient client) {
    this.sslCtx = sslCtx;
    this.client=client;
}

@Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    // Add SSL handler first to encrypt and decrypt everything.
    pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc(), client.getHost(), client.getPort()));
    pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());
    // Remove the following line if you don't want automatic content decompression.
    pipeline.addLast("inflater", new HttpContentDecompressor());

    // Uncomment the following line if you don't want to handle HttpChunks.
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
    pipeline.addLast(new NestClientHandler(client));
}
```

}

Comment: You can't do streaming with automatic aggregating, you need to manually  append the messages if you want to implement streaming

Comment: thanks, I didn't see your reply, but figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I don't have control over what the server is sending, and it isn't sending a blank Http message or other indicator of the end of each message. I had to write my own handler for the chunking, so I could be sure it was getting chunked properly given the lack of breaks in the data stream. I used the HttpObjectAggregator code as an example and added my own logic.